# Improve the free function - job interview

Tags: c, memory-management, free, allocation

I had a job interview and I was asked the following question:

> The `free()` function is too "expensive."  We want to implement a function
>   named `myFree()` with the prototype `void myFree( void* p )`. 
>   `myFree` needs to save the pointer `p` in some way, instead of what
>   the `free()` function would do.

At the moment, when the programmer decides to free the pointers which he saved by the `myFree` function, he use the function `myFinalFree()`.

I have only one global pointer that I can use when implementing `myFree`, therefore I can't allocate any extra memory.

Any ideas for `myFree`?

Comment: You will have to be more specific with the problem.

Comment: the most obvious solution is organize linked list from freed memory. may be where is more interesting solution?

Comment: I can't be more specific.
The problem with linked list is that you "lose" the object that the pointr is referenced to

Comment: My answer would be to call free less often.  If you can invest the time to write the code to act as a secondary memory manager, you can invest the time optimizing the caller to stop behaving in such a manner.

Comment: They insisted on the implementation of myFree

Comment: Imagine what they might insist upon if you actually worked there!

Comment: Very interesting interview question, it lead to so many questions about implementation. See [Joel Spolsky blog](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000073.html).

Comment: It makes no sense wrapping free() if you don't wrap malloc() calloc() and realloc() too.

Comment: My suggestion to you is that you learn how a heap actually works by doing it. Suppose you have functions `big_malloc` and `big_free` which act just like `malloc` and `free` except that their argument must be a multiple of 16K; they can only allocated 16K blocks at a time. **Can you use those two methods to implement `malloc` and `free` efficiently?** If you can do so then you will be able to answer questions like this one with ease.

Comment: @wildplasser: Why's that?  They're not the ones with bad performance, by the assumption of the question.

Comment: Because without such companion functions you would never be able to regain and reuse the myfree()d memory, and it would be basically lost. (equivalent to `void myfree(void *p) { return; }` , which is *very* efficient ;-)

Comment: @wildplasser: By "never" you mean "until `myFinalFree` is called", yes? How is that the same as "never"?

Comment: MyFinalFree() will only pospone the actions of free(). Remember: for every malloc() et.al. there must be a matching free(). Also: the program would consume more address space.

Comment: `void myfree(void *p) {freelist[fp++] = p;}` `void myfinalfree() {while (fp) free(freelist[--fp]); }`

Comment: @wildplasser: Right, so we are trading time *now* for time *later*, which might be a good choice; if the time later is while the program is otherwise idle, that's a good tradeoff. Who cares if it uses more address space? Address space in 64 bit architectures is abundant.

Answer (score 3):

**You can manage the pointers in a linked-list:**

- Initialize a global `head=0`
- Inside function `myFree(p)`:

  1. Set the value at the address pointed by `p` to the value of `head`
  2. Set the value of `head` to the value of `p`
- Inside function `myFinalFree()`:

  1. Start from `head` and free all pointers until reaching 0
  2. Set the value of `head` back to 0

**Here is a coding example:**

```
typedef int t_ptr;

static t_ptr head = 0;

void myFree(void* p)
{
    if (p)
    {
        *(t_ptr*)p = head;
        head = (t_ptr)p;
    }
}

void myFinalFree()
{
    t_ptr* p = (t_ptr*)head;
    while (p)
    {
        head = *p;
        free(p);
        p = (t_ptr*)head;
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- You have to make sure that `sizeof(t_ptr) == sizeof(void*)`
- The above code works under the assumption that `malloc` always allocates at least `sizeof(void*)` bytes, aligned to an address which is a multiple of `sizeof(void*)`

Comment: Wouldn't this segfault in cases where the user is trying to free a block of memory smaller than a pointer? Also I think in most cases, `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: before calling myfree p was pointing to an object...
after myfree p is pointing to head ...
is it a problem while doing  free(p) in myFinalFree ??

Comment: @SimpleJ: `malloc` typically allocates a minimum of `sizeof(void*)` bytes, aligned to a multiple of `sizeof(void*)`. So you can call `malloc(1)`, but in effect, at least 4 or 8 bytes will be allocated.

Comment: @SimpleJ: It is highly unlikely to segfault (see my recent article on that subject http://ericlippert.com/2014/05/07/why-does-my-code-not-crash/) Rather it is highly likely to corrupt heap data structures, should the allocation actually be small.

Comment: @barakmanos: The fact that your code depends on an implementation detail of malloc should be stated somewhere.

Comment: @barakmanos: Also, your code behaves poorly when passed null. Remember, null is a legal input to free.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Yep, just added that (before I saw your comment).

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Regarding the `NULL` issue - I must have at least one known value to state an invalid memory address. Since I have no idea regarding the memory mapping of the underlying platform, I have to rely on 0. I can use `~0`, but that has equal chances of being a viable memory address on the bus...

Comment: @barakmanos: I fixed it for you, so it will handle a NULL parameter to `myFree`.

Comment: @abelenky: Thanks. I accept your fix, but my usual argument against it is this: what if some user calls `malloc((void*)0xFBFBFBFB)`? I'm basically saying that it protects only a single illegal argument out of many others...

Comment: `0/NULL` is a **valid** argument!  To be compliant, you must accept 0, and process it without faulting.  If someone calls `myFree(0xFBFBFBFB);`, then you are allowed to crash.

Comment: can you please exsplain why it is not a problem:
suppose p was the output of malloc(500).
so the pointer that we do free(p) for it , is pointing to an object of size 500 .
in myFree function P is pointing to head which is not of size 500 ... and in function myFinalFree we do free(p) .... isn't it a problem  ?

Comment: @user3175582: It's not like function `free` "goes and frees" every single byte in the allocated block of memory. Read a little bit about *Memory Heap* in order to understand how it works. The blocks themselves are managed in a linked-list, where, at the beginning of each block, the address of the next block is written. Since the size of an address is typically 4 or 8 bytes (depending on your system), there is no problem with a block of 500 bytes.

Comment: @user3175582: `p` is never pointing to `head`. Why do you believe that `p` points to `head`?  `p` is *equal* to `head`, and that's completely different. Suppose you have three pieces of paper, one labelled `p 1`, one labelled `head 2` and one labelled `3`. On pieces of paper `p 1` and `head 2` you also write `3`. So `p` and `head` are equal; they both point to piece of paper `3`. If `p` pointed to `head` then it would say `2` on the piece of paper, not `3`.